# Is this ordering guaranteed?

Tags: lua

Is this script:

```
local data = 
{
  { "data1",    "1"},
  { "data5",    "2"},
  { "3453453",  "3"},
  { "zzz",      "4"},
  { "222",      "5"},
  { "lol",      "6"},
  { "asdf",     "7"},
  { "hello",    "8"},
}

local function test()
 local count = #data
  for i = 1, count do
    print(data[i][1] .. " = " .. data[i][2])
  end
end

test()
```

Guaranteed to output:

```
data1 = 1
data5 = 2
3453453 = 3
zzz = 4
222 = 5
lol = 6
asdf = 7
hello = 8
```

If not then why, and what is best way performance wise to make it so?

Comment: Why wouldn't it output that?

Comment: I read something about pairs VS ipairs not returning a fixed order of results, I figured maybe using an index up to # might be the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I read something about pairs VS ipairs not returning a fixed order of results

`ipairs` is an iterator of the array elements of a table, *in order* from first to last. "Array elements" being defined as the members of a table with keys that are numeric values on the range `[1, #tbl]`, where `#tbl` is the length operator applied to the table.

`pairs` is an iterator over *all* of the elements of a table: array and non-array elements alike. Non-array elements of a table have no intrinsic order to Lua, so `pairs` will return them in any order. And even though the array elements do technically have an order, `pairs` will not make an exception for them; it always operates in an arbitrary order.

Your code works like `ipairs`: iterating over each of the numeric keys of the table from 1 to its length.

Comment: I'm confused.. my table has no "numeric keys"? They are both strings?

Comment: @paulm: "*my table has no "numeric keys"*" When you create a table with values that have no keys, Lua automatically assigns numeric keys to those values.

Comment: Ah bingo, thats the bit I was missing!